# How to add line to system configuration file with sudo?

Tags: command-line-interface, sudo

I need add a line to a configuration file (e.g. /etc/resolv.conf). If I use

`sudo echo "nameserver 192.168.1.6" >> /etc/resolv.conf`

I get error message Access denied. Problem is that bash write to file from my account, not from roots account.

Is there any way how to get it works?

I know there is a "solution" to write my commands into file and run them as batch but it is strongly uncomfortable :-(

Comment: <3 'sudo echo'. "Won't you take me to, a funky town?" :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "nameserver 192.168.1.6" >> /etc/resolv.conf'
```

Answer (score 13):

`echo "nameserver 192.168.1.6" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf`